# Why do I get error when filtering Odata entities by a related one property from a cloud based D365 F&O?

Tags: c#, odata, microsoft-dynamics

I need to get all the ProductSpecificOrderSettingsV3 of ReleasedProductV2 with a specific VendorAccountNumber from a cloud based FFO environment using Odata, but I receive an error from the server I don't understand.

The linq query I use for this is:

```
var qr_1= from t in context.ProductSpecificOrderSettingsV3
where t.ReleasedProductV2.PrimaryVendorAccountNumber == "3401000185"
select t;
```

I see that it is correctly translated in the following request to the server

> .../data/ProductSpecificOrderSettingsV3?$filter=ReleasedProductV2/PrimaryVendorAccountNumber eq '3401000185'

but I receive the error:

> "message":"Instance property 'ReleasedProductV2' is not defined for type 'Dynamics.AX.Application.Services.OData.EntityExtensions.ProductSpecificOrderSettingV3_3b5b7c0f314e456cbba9c8e34bd4aaa1.InventProductSpecificOrderSettingsV3Entity'", "type":"System.ArgumentException"

I cannot understand the error becaouse of the relation exist, in fact this query works:

```
var qr_1= from t in context.ProductSpecificOrderSettingsV3
select new {t.ReleasedProductV2.ItemNumber, t.MinimumProcurementOrderQuantity};
```

> .../data/ProductSpecificOrderSettingsV3?$expand=ReleasedProductV2($select=ItemNumber)&$select=MinimumProcurementOrderQuantity}

I'm doind something wrong or filtering an entity by a related one property is not possible in
D365 Finance & Operation environment?